Losing frames while displaying from the camera that is read with gstreamer
I’m trying to display and save videos from my FLIR Hadron Camera, I’m using GStreamer in Python 3 OpenCV ,and it successfully displays and saves the IR videos from the BOSON, but I’m losing frames in the RGB videos, which leads to slow displaying and fast playback, and tried to add various commands to the GStreamer pipelines, such as videorate, to control the fps, but nothing help.
I checked while executing the code that it's using just the CPU part of the Jetson Nano , so I've installed CUDA to be able to use the GPU, and I don't know what I've got to add in my code to force it to use the GPU of the computer.
Here is the RGB code for displaying and saving:
import cv2

camset='v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(camset,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if cap.isOpened() is not True:
    print("Cannot open camera. Exiting.")
    quit()
actual_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
actual_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
actual_fps = float(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS));
print('Capture opened framing %d x %d @ %f' % (actual_width,actual_height,actual_fps))

gst_writer_str = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h265enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=14000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=streaming.mp4'
fourcc = 0 #RAW
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_writer_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, actual_fps, (actual_width, actual_height), True)
if not out.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open writer. Exiting.")
    quit()

while (True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


You are using the wrong order, " waitkey" should come right after "imshow", and write the frames using a new thread (process) so you don't lose the frames.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/gstreamer-losing-frames-while-displaying-from-the-camera/17447

what do you suppose that videorate and drop=1 do?

i used the videorate parameter to adjust the frame rate of a video stream, and The appsink drop=1 parameter helps to prevent the accumulation of frames in the sink's internal buffer when the consuming application cannot keep up with the rate of incoming frames. i added this parameters to help with the frame lose but nothing worked ,i'd appreciate it any help thank you

I think that is the reason you lose frames. either there, or in the writer. you do a lot of gstreamer stuff in this piece of code

Hey, i really appreciate your help.  i tried and deleted the videorate and drop=1 it didn’t help. it’s an opencv problem because when i execute the same gstreamer pipline in the terminal the display is fluide but in the python3 script i’m losing frames in the cap.read() part i truly have no idea how to solve this problem to stop losing frames.


I checked while executing the code that it's using just the CPU part of the Jetson Nano , so I've installed CUDA to be able to use the GPU, and I don't know what I've got to add in my code to force it to use the GPU of the computer.

Using GPU with OpenCv CUDA processing is possible, but this wouldn't help your case as you're not processing the frames in the loop, just reading from gstreamer and pushing to gstreamer and displaying with imshow.
gstreamer leverages use of dedicated HW from Jetson such as NVENC (HW encoder, not available with Orin Nano), NVDEC (HW decoder) and VIC (for resizing, cropping or converting to another format) drived by nvvidconv element that can also copy between NVMM memory (DMAable for HW blocks) and system memory.
imshow may be the bootleneck for a Jetson Nano at high resolution and framerate. You may try to lower these and check if it improves.
An alternative would be to use an opencv VideoWriter with a displaysink, such as these pipelines:
display_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! xvimagesink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

# Or:
display_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvoverlaysink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

# Or:
display_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=I420 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw ! xvimagesink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

# Or:
display_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

Create the second VideoWriter with one of these pipelines and same parameters as for the writer to file, and check it is successfully opened.
In the loop, you would remove imshow and instead write the frame into the display writer.

hey Seb thank you for your answer i've tried the changes you've suggested but they didn't work since the problem is not imshow i'm losing frames just with reading from the camera in the 'ret,frame=cap.read()' my goal with this code is to stream to a server so i thought that i can just another pipline to the capset that would stream to the server with 30 fps and display to the appsink with 1/5 fps  and that would be no problem if the streaming is 30fps , can you check my code below:

Do you need opencv ? You can use gstreamer only for that. I'd suggest to capture specifying a native framerate for your camera such as one listed by v4l2-ctl -d0 --list-formats-ext for 1920x1080 in UYVY format. You may use videorate element in the opencv capture branch for reducing frame rate.

Does the pure gstreamer pipeline works ? gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! tee name=t   t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink   t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://zkms.waldwaechter.de/live/rgb

If ok, you may try this opencv capture gst pipeline: camset='v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! tee name=t   t. ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=5/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink    t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc idrinterval=30 insert-sps-pps=1 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://zkms.waldwaechter.de/live/rgb'

Hey thank you for your help the camset you provided did display but couldn't stream to my server and i don't get any error in the terminal  . by the way would it possible to delete the comments that includes the url i shouldn't have mention that in my comment , thank you for your understanding
